# Reversing an Object.entries conversion

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am using `Object.entries` in order to get some values out of a nested object and filter it.

```
obj = Object.entries(obj)
  .filter(([k, v]) => {
    return true; // some irrelevant conditions here
  });
```

My object ends up as an array of arrays, of keys and vals.

```
[['key1', val]['key2', val]['key3', val]]
```

Is there a straightforward way to map these back into an object? The original object structure is:

```
{ key:val, key2:val2, key3:val3 }
```

Comment: [`array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) should make it pretty straightforwad

Comment: Just loop through the array, adding properties to the resulting object. What's the problem?

Comment: Why use `Object.entries()` instead of `for (k in obj)`? It seems like you're just making things more complicated.

Comment: I'd agree with you, but `for..in loops iterate over the entire prototype chain, which is virtually never what you want. Use Object.{keys,values,entries}, and iterate over the resulting array.`. Its not so relevant here but I want to get in the practise of writing scalable code.

Comment: @userqwert For in loops iterate over the entire prototype chain, which virtually never contains enumerable properties, so it does not matter. To write scalable code, just use a `Map` for your collections.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Sure, just use `.reduce` to assign to a new object:

```js
const input = { key:'val', key2:'val2', key3:'val3' };

const output = Object.entries(input)
  .filter(([k, v]) => {
    return true; // some irrelevant conditions here
  })
  .reduce((accum, [k, v]) => {
    accum[k] = v;
    return accum;
  }, {});
console.log(output);
```

In modern browsers, you can also use [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) which makes this even easier - you can just pass an array of entries, and it'll create the object from those entries.

```js
const input = { key:'val', key2:'val2', key3:'val3' };

const output = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(input)
    .filter(([k, v]) => {
      return true; // some irrelevant conditions here
    })
);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 22):

For new browsers, use Object.fromEntries:

```
Object.fromEntries(arr);
```

For older js, it can still be a **one liner**.

```
arr.reduce((acc,[k,v])=>(acc[k]=v,acc),{})
```

Example:

```
Object.entries(sampleObject) // Turn object to array
   .reduce((acc,[k,v])=>(acc[k]=v,acc),{}) // Turn it back to object.
```

Comment: @chickens, thanks for your answer, do you mind explaining shortly the ES6+ line?

Comment: The one liner works but doesn't pass eslint with the comma after the "=v,"

Answer (score 8):

Using Object.assign with a map that maps `[k,v]` => `{[k]: v}`

For example, the code below will only keep keys beginning with `key`

```js
var obj = {
  key: 1,
  key2: 2,
  key3: 3,
  removed: 4,
  alsoRemoved: 5
}

obj = Object.assign({}, ...Object.entries(obj)
    .filter(([k, v]) => {
        return k.startsWith('key');
    })
    .map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: v}))
);

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using reduce with [deconstruction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [comma operator](https://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/6524-the-confusing-comma-in-javascript.html):

```
const input = { key:'val', key2:'val2', key3:'val3' };

const output = Object.entries(input)
  .filter(([k, v]) => {
     return true; // some irrelevant conditions here
  })
  .reduce((acc, [k, v]) => (acc[k] = v, acc), {});
```

which should give the same functionality as CertainPerformance's answer with a bit more concise syntax

Answer (score 1):

```js
let entries = Object.entries({e: 'e', q: 'q'});
let reverse = entries.map(([t, r]) => ({[t]: r})).reduce((pv, cv) =>{return Object.assign(pv, cv)});
console.log(reverse);
```

Comment: Consider to add some feedback of what the code does to make it easier to understand

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you know exactly which entries you want to exclude, you can use object deconstruction combined with spreading:

```
function clean(obj) {
  const { unwanted1, unwanted2, ...wanted } = obj;
  return { ...wanted };
}
```

For some cases, this might be the cleanest solution.

Comment: Neat! Couldn't `return { ...wanted };` be simplified to `return wanted;`? This is also an ES 2018 feature, so may be slightly less widely supported: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/#test-object_rest/spread_properties

Answer (score -1):

```js
function undoEntries(entered){
  let output = {};
  entered.forEach(item => {
    output[item[0]] = item[1]
  });
  return output;
};
// Example
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
const input = Object.entries(obj);
const output = undoEntries(input);
console.log(output);
```