# Convert array of object with different key into one object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an object like below.

```
{
  A: { lists: 2, list: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  B: { lists: 2, list: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  C: { lists: 1, list: [ [Object]] }
}
```

After I do a map on an object list result, like below

```
 const list = Object.entries(result).map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: v.lists}));
```

the result I am getting is

```
[{"A":2},{"B":2},{"C":1}]
```

But what I actually want is

```
{A: 2, B: 2, C: 1}
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: @SagiRika nope.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reversing an Object.entries conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49807489/reversing-an-object-entries-conversion)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you map the entries change them to `[k, v.lists]`, and then convert to an object using [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries):

```js
const result = { A: { lists: 2 }, B: { lists: 2 }, C: { lists: 1 }};

const list = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(result).map(([k, v]) => [k, v.lists]));

console.log(list);
```

With lodash you can use `_.mapValues()` to use `lists` as the values of the properties:

```js
const result = { A: { lists: 2 }, B: { lists: 2 }, C: { lists: 1 }};

const list = _.mapValues(result, 'lists');

console.log(list);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` as follows.

```
const list = Object.entries(result).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => {
  acc[k] = v.lists;
  return acc;
}, {});
```